# windows non-boot raid

Tags: windows, raid

I'm thinking about installing Ubuntu on a Windows machine for dual boot. There are three Windows drives `c:` and `d:` are independent and `g:` is a RAID (0/1 I think).

What do I need to do to get the RAID recognized under Linux? (A previous attempt on a similar computer resulted in 2 separate drives - but that was not dual boot.)